List Dict to rows/columns in dataframe
I'm a complete beginner at python, and I'm trying to convert a json payload into a dataframe.
So I've got data that looks like this:
data = {
    "results": [
        {"values": [{"name": "firstname","value": "Fname1"},{"name": "lastname","value": "Lname1"}]},
        {"values": [{"name": "firstname","value": "Fname2"},{"name": "lastname","value": "Lname2"}]},
        {"values": [{"name": "firstname","value": "Fname3"},{"name": "lastname","value": "Lname3"}]}
    ]
}

I want a dataframe that looks like this:



firstname
lastname




Fname1
Lname1


Fname2
Lname2


Fname3
Lname3



I'm trying to figure out how to do this without doing something like a for loop or manually assigning column names. Thanks!
Kinda tried something like this:
df = pd.DataFrame(data["results"])

df[['values'][0]].apply(lambda x: x[0]['value'])

which result in:








Fname1


Fname2


Fname3



But I'm kinda stuck on what to do next.

I would use a nested list/dictionary comprehension to pass to the DataFrame constructor:
out = pd.DataFrame([{d['name']: d['value']
                     for d in l['values']}
                    for l in data['results']])

Output:
  firstname lastname
0    Fname1   Lname1
1    Fname2   Lname2
2    Fname3   Lname3

Intermediate before passing to DataFrame:
[{'firstname': 'Fname1', 'lastname': 'Lname1'},
 {'firstname': 'Fname2', 'lastname': 'Lname2'},
 {'firstname': 'Fname3', 'lastname': 'Lname3'}]


Make a helper function to pre-process your data before loading it in to a DataFrame.
def parser(data):
    for item in data:
        vals = item["values"]
        tmp = {}
        for val in vals:
            k, v = val.values()
            tmp[k] = v
        yield tmp

Call it and then you can load it in.
tmp = parser(data["results"])
pd.DataFrame(tmp)

  firstname lastname
0    Fname1   Lname1
1    Fname2   Lname2
2    Fname3   Lname3


One way to do this is to read your data using json_normalize, align the index to the values and then pivot the result:
out = (pd
    .json_normalize(data['results'], 'values')
    .pipe(lambda df:df.set_index(df.index // 2))
    .pivot(columns='name', values='value')
)

Output:
name firstname lastname
0       Fname1   Lname1
1       Fname2   Lname2
2       Fname3   Lname3

Note this code is dependent on each entry having the same number of values. If they are not the same, it will not work. If the number is different to 2, the divisor in the set_index call needs to be changed to that value.
Note also that reformatting the data using straight python (as described in the other 3 answers) would almost certainly be more efficient.

I had a similar approach in mind for a moment but there is a serious drawback IMO: this relies on having exactly two dictionaries per list (if you have more or less this will mixup rows). Also the processing is most likely not as efficient as pure python in this case.

It's just to bad that json_normalize doesn't have a mechanism to group/index rows based on the presence in a common list (and doesn't maintain the original index when run on a Series) :(

@mozway don't you ever sleep?! :) but seriously, I agree about json_normalize, it really should give records from the same list the same index. I also agree this is dependent on the data format and undoubtedly not as efficient as the nested list/dict comprehension. I just wanted to offer an alternative.

@mozway I've added an essay about the limitations of the code :)

I agree it's always nice to show alternatives, json_normalize was also my first idea and I then thought a nested comprehension might just be easier. Many possibilities. Thanks for updating ;)

In this scenario, I would make the sure data is in the format that I want before creating the DataFrame.
new_data = []
for i in data['results']:
    row = {}
    for j in i['values']:
        row[j['name']] = j['value']
    new_data.append(row)

print(new_data)

[{'firstname': 'Fname1', 'lastname': 'Lname1'},
 {'firstname': 'Fname2', 'lastname': 'Lname2'},
 {'firstname': 'Fname3', 'lastname': 'Lname3'}]

Then you can easily create the DataFrame with pd.DataFrame(new_data).

data = {
    "results": [
        {"values": [{"name": "firstname", "value": "Fname1"}, {"name": "lastname", "value": "Lname1"}]},
        {"values": [{"name": "firstname", "value": "Fname2"}, {"name": "lastname", "value": "Lname2"}]},
        {"values": [{"name": "firstname", "value": "Fname3"}, {"name": "lastname", "value": "Lname3"}]}
    ]
}

values_list = [ {i['name'] : i['value'] for i in res['values']} for res in data['results']] 

df = pd.DataFrame(values_list)

print(df)
"""
  firstname lastname
0    Fname1   Lname1
1    Fname2   Lname2
2    Fname3   Lname3
"""

